# InterfaceError in Python (Flask, SQLAlchemy) - Error binding parameter of a db.relationship parameter

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm very new to Flask and SQLAlchemy but have a foundational understanding of Python.  This is also my first post here and I think I've looked extensively for an answer to my problem.

I'm trying to create a very simple family tree database.  I have two tables - a table of individuals, and a table of families (each family has an optional father and an optional mother - each of which is a foreign key representing another individual in the individuals table).

The individuals are created with a mandatory surname and optional fore and middle names.  Also in the individuals table is a column with a relationship to the family table.

When I try to run this code, I get an error -

sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 3 - probably unsupported type.
[SQL: INSERT INTO individual (forename, middle_name, surname, family_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('David', None, 'Bloggs', <RelationshipProperty at 0x4314c68; no key>)]

The code is:

```js
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///"+os.path.join(basedir,"data.sqlite")
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
Migrate(app, db)

class Family(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "family"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    mother_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey("individual.id"))
    father_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey("individual.id"))


    def __init__(self,mother_id='',father_id=''):
        self.mother_id = mother_id
        self.father_id = father_id


class Individual(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "individual"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    forename = db.Column(db.Text)
    middle_name = db.Column(db.Text)
    surname = db.Column(db.Text)
    family_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey("family.id"))

    def __init__(self,surname,forename=None,middle_name=None):
        self.forename = forename
        self.middle_name = middle_name
        self.surname = surname
        self.family_id = db.relationship("family",backref="individual",lazy="dynamic")

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"""The individual is {self.forename} {self.middle_name}
        {self.surname}, their father is {self.family.father_id.forename}
        {self.family.father_id.middle_name} {self.family.father_id.surname}
        and their mother is {self.family.mother_id.forename}
        {self.family.mother_id.middle_name} {self.family.mother_id.surname}"""

db.create_all()

person1 = Individual("Bloggs", "David")
person2 = Individual("Bloggs", "Robert")
person3 = Individual("Smith", "Mary", "Ann")

db.session.add_all([person1,person2,person3])
db.session.commit()

print(person1)
print(person2)
print(person3)
```

Any help appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it´s neccesary to talk about a point in your Database design

The DB needs a double relationship bewteen Family and Individual, because to create a Individual is neccesary a Family, on another place, to create a Family is necesary a mother and father id. This is a problem.
A way to design this is assign a familiy_id and every individual takes a family_id and a role in the family.

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///"+os.path.join(basedir,"data.sqlite")
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
Migrate(app, db)

class Family(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "family"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    family_id = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True)
    family_name = db.Column(db.Text)


    def __init__(self,family_id, family_name):
        self.family_id = family_id
        self.family_name = family_name


class Individual(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "individual"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    forename = db.Column(db.Text)
    middle_name = db.Column(db.Text)
    surname = db.Column(db.Text)
    role = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        nullable=False,
        server_default=db.text("'0'"),
        comment="Indicates whether is the role in the family . 2 = Father, 1= Mother, 0 = Other",
    )
    family_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey("family.id"))

    def __init__(self, forename, middle_name, surname, family_id, role=0):
        self.forename = forename
        self.middle_name = middle_name
        self.surname = surname
        self.family_id = family_id
        self.role = role

   
db.create_all()

family = Family(1, "Kay Fam.")

son = Individual("John", "David", "Kay", 1)
father = Individual("Dave", "Luis", "Kay", 1, 2)

db.session.add(family)
db.session.add(son)
db.session.add(father)

db.session.commit()
```

New case:
To assign a Individual to multiple Family/Role is neccesary to modify

```
 class Individual(db.Model):


    __tablename__ = "individual"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    individual_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    forename = db.Column(db.Text)
    middle_name = db.Column(db.Text)
    surname = db.Column(db.Text)
    role = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        nullable=False,
        server_default=db.text("'0'"),
        comment="Indicates whether is the role in the family . 2 = Father, 1= Mother, 0 = Other",
    )
    family_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey("family.id"))

    def __init__(self, individual_id,  forename, middle_name, surname, family_id, role=0):
        self.individual_id = individual_id
        self.forename = forename
        self.middle_name = middle_name
        self.surname = surname
        self.family_id = family_id
        self.role = role
```

The individual_id its important, why? Because is not unique and its a number associated to the individual (The id indicates the position on the DB, the individual_id == DNI for example)
With this is possible to add the individual with differents familiy/roles more than one time.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense.  I just have one more follow up question then = an individual can be a child in one family and a mother/father in one or more other families - does this mean this DB design would need to change somehow?  Would you have a separate Relationships table perhaps, which links a family ID with an individual ID and a role type?  Thanks again for your time, it is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, i edit the answer with your quiestions. 
Regards

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and time, much appreciated.